# is Dojo more helpful than using normal Javascript+jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, dojo

I really wonder why do we want to go for dojo when there is JavaScript with jQuery?

I have already used  HTML and **jQuery** for one of my django project. And also used **dojo** for my another django project.

Now i am going to do another **django** project and I am very confused which on should i have to use?

Is there any more advantages when we are using Dojo

Comment: it depends on what are you gonna do, both jquery and dojo are defenitely faster than html+js on large applications.

Comment: So you ask about Dojo vs. jQuery alternative, and not Dojo vs. vanilla HTML+JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will help you in deciding:

### Dojo:

> Dojo is used for creating dynamic web user interfaces by providing
>   widgets, high level Input and Output abstraction and utilities. Dojo
>   enables rapid development across platforms between JavaScript, Ajax
>   and web applications. Dojo is a rapid development toolkit for web
>   oriented software on desktop and mobile and internet applications
>   without using the browser’s inbuilt graphics technology. Dojo is being
>   used by all the popular internet browsers like Internet Explorer,
>   Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera and on smart phones and tablets
>   by Apple (iPhone, iPad) Google ( Android) and BlackBerry.

### jQuery:

> JQuery is a JavaScript library whereas Dojo is a JavaScript toolkit.
>   JQuery provides the easy interaction between HTML and JavaScript
>   through JavaScript Library. It is used for handling events, creating
>   animations, reading and manipulating HTML document and creating Ajax
>   application with Ajax ASP.net and PHP. Query allows the customization
>   of plug-ins library on top of inbuilt JavaScript libraries. JQuery
>   provides User Interface libraries with many useful functionalities.
>   JQuery is easy to use and customization feature is making it popular
>   and adoption is all time high.

Read more about them @ [this article](http://www.worthofweb.com/blog/is-jquery-better-than-dojo/).

In my opinion it totally depends on what type of website you are making because they are somewhat different from each other.

Comment: and if you like it give it a +1 :)